# SQL Server Query - Lookup from one table to another

Tags: sql-server

Can anyone please help - See below two tables

```
Table - Master
Field 1 - Id
Field 2 - Name
Field 3 - Address
Field 4 - Effective End Date
Filed 5 - Last updated date

Table - Child
Field 1 - Id
Field 2 - Name
Field 3 - Address
```

I need to do lookup from Parent in child and if Parent record doesn't exist (based on Id, Name and Address) then update the effective end date and last updated date of Table Master.

New to SQL, so struggling with this basic query.

Regards

Comment: Struggling to right update query for this? I don't know how to implement lookup think in update command. So table-master need to lookup in Table-Child and if Table-master record doesn't exists then i need update date fields

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
UPDATE  m
SET     [Effective End Date] = GETDATE()
        , [Last updated date] = GETDATE()
FROM    Master m
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT  *
    FROM    Child c 
    WHERE   c.Id = m.Id
    AND     c.Name = m.Name
    AND     c.Address = m.Address
)
```

If you want to update records in `Master` when a record with same `Id, Name, Address` does not exist in `Child` table you can do it like this. There's also an `OUTPUT` clause that returns rows affected by the update. The dates are being updated to today's date but you can set that to anything you need.

Here is an **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6f93c/3/1)**

Comment: I need to check for NOT EXISTS condition in child table

Comment: @ConradJagger OK, so if there is a record in `Master` but there is no corresponding record in `Child`, `Master` should be updated? If that's the case `EXISTS` should be changed to `NOT EXISTS` and it will work.

Comment: You added the `NOT` back but didn't change the description part of your answer. It's still related to the `EXISTS` version of the query.

Answer (score 1):

> I need to do lookup from Parent in child and if Parent record doesn't exist (based on Id, Name and Address) then update the effective end date and last updated date of Table Master.

Are you looking for `IF` and `EXISTS`?

```
IF EXISTS(
  SELECT 1 FROM Child c
  WHERE Id = @Id
  AND   Name = @Name
  AND   Address = @Address
) 
BEGIN
    UPDATE Master 
    SET [Effective End Date] = @EffectiveEndDate
        [Last updated date]  = @LastUpdatedDate
    WHERE Id = @Id
    AND   Name = @Name
    AND   Address = @Address 
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
Update Master  Set [Effective End Date] = GETDATE(), 
[Last updated date] = GETDATE()
Where id  not in ( select distinct id from Child)
```

Simple